# FInd all winning moves for given Nim position (Misere version)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinatorial-game-theory

I have two Nim position

1. 2,5,8,15
2. 5,7,8,10

The question asks me to find all the winning moves (not to end the game but all the possible moves that lead to a winning situation) for the given Nim positions, assume that I'm in a losing position. However, I found that the two positions above both have even parity, so I could not find the winning moves for both.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "Even parity" isn't the criterion.  Read about the nim sum again. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nim#Mathematical_theory

Comment: The nim sum of 2,5,6 and 8 is 0 so I could not know what move to make

Comment: I get 9 as the nim sum.

Comment: Sorry I mistyped the question, the first one is 2,5,8 and 15

Comment: Now I agree with you; both nim sums are 0.  In both cases, there is no winning move, as you say, and that should be the answer to the question.